# Can this ESP wifi board's firmware be rewritten?

Tags: wireless, esp8266, nodemcu

I'm new to all this node mcu thing. I'm searching for relay shields because they're ready and well soldered, so I can put them into my light switches with no effort.

[image]

I've found this pack which already comes with the ESP and a custom firmware. I don't want to trust a strange firmware, I want to upload my own and play with it.

Can this `ESP8266 ESP-01S`'s firmware be rewritten, and if so, which equipment I'll need?

[link for the product](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/ESP8266-ESP-01S-5V-WiFi-Relay-Module-Things-Smart-Home-Remote-Control-Switch-for-Arduino-Phone/32841061942.html)

Comment: you can use an Uno to program it. or any usb serial adapter, like a cp2102 or ch340g.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you see the black module ? It's just a generic ESP 8266 module (ESP-01, to be precise).

According to what I found on the Internet: Yes, you can.

For more information, you should read [this](http://remotexy.com/en/help/esp8266-firmware-update/).

Comment: I don't have a problem with it being generic. Do you mean I can update the official one, the generic one, or both?

Comment: In short, yes..

Comment: Wait... I didn't understand. The generic one can be updated?

Comment: Yes, I think they all have serial bootloader. The only problem is the pinout, but in this case, yes.

Comment: What is the problem with the pin out?

Comment: For such small module, not all IC pins gets pinned out. But for this module, neccessary pins (for communicating with the host, doing firmware update) have been pinned out.